# Reverse many-to-many Dictionary<key, List<value>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

Actually [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324912/convert-dictionaryint-enumerable-to-dictionaryint-enumerable-inverting-cont) got me thinking
and I realized that reversing a `Dictionary` is not trivial.
What is the most elegant and readable way to do it?

Same scenario student Many to Many with Classes

original `Dicitonary<int, List<int>>` where the key is studentId and the Value is a `List<int>` that contains classId and want to revert to `Dictionary<classId, List<studentId>>`

Thanks

Update:
Actually I just tested Luke and Bruno's solutions and they return the right amount of classed whoever they all have the same student, will update as i go along.

Comment: @Pins if an answer solves your problem satisfactorily, I recommend clicking the "checkmark" next to it to accept it as the official answer and reward the person who gave it.

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slightly different way (a bit more comprehensible to my brain anyway :) ...

```
var newDict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
dict.Add( 1, new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );
dict.Add( 2, new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );
dict.Add( 3, new List<int>() { 1, 2, 6 } );
dict.Add( 4, new List<int>() { 1, 6, 7 } );
dict.Add( 5, new List<int>() { 8 } );

var newKeys = dict.Values.SelectMany( v => v ).Distinct();

foreach( var nk in newKeys )
{
   var vals = dict.Keys.Where( k => dict[k].Contains(nk) );
   newDict.Add( nk, vals.ToList() );
}
```

Answer (score 48):

To reverse a dictionary is very easy:

```
var newDic = oldDic.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);
```

That's all.

Now, your question is different. It is about reversing a many-to-many relationship, established on a dictionary.

So, let's say you have Dictionary<TEntity1, IEnumerable<TEntity2>>. The idea is to extract from this the "middle table" of the many-to-many relationship. Then you can regroup it by the other side, and retransform into a dictionary.

For the first part, we will use the overload of SelectMany that

> "Projects each element of a sequence to
>   an IEnumerable<T>,
>   flattens the resulting sequences into
>   one sequence, and invokes a result
>   selector function on each element
>   therein."

```
var table =
    dict.SelectMany(
        x => x.Value,
        (dictEntry, entryElement) => new
               {
                      Entity1 = dictEntry.Key,
                      Entity2 = entryElement
               }
    );
```

So, now you just have to regroup this table the way you want, and then convert it to a dictionary.

```
 var newDict =
     table
         .GroupBy(x => x.Entity2,
                  x => x.Entity1,
                  (entity2, entity1) => new {entity1, entity2})
         .ToDictionary(x => x.entity2, x => x.entity1);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to ensure that the Values are unique

Comment: This is not correct. Read the contents of the question - it does not make sense to key off a list of class IDs for a single student ID.

Comment: I just tried that and the result is a Dictionary<List<int>, int> I m afraid that is not what I m looking for. Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: By giving the most logical answer to the thread title, you completely failed to answer the content of the question inside. Interesting.

Comment: Take it easy, guys! I was editing it since when I saw the contents of the question!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly how this differs from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324912/convert-dictionaryint-enumerable-to-dictionaryint-enumerable-inverting-cont).

If you're just asking how to return a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` rather than `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>` then all you need is a call to the [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method.

Stealing and amending [Mehrdad's answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324912/convert-dictionaryint-enumerable-to-dictionaryint-enumerable-inverting-cont/1325003#1325003):

```
var classToStudent = studentToClass
    .SelectMany(
        pair => pair.Value.Select(val => new { Key = val, Value = pair.Key }))
    .GroupBy(item => item.Key)
    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Select(item => item.Value).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, I was trying to find a simpler solution :D , I find that very cool tho hard to read. I cant understand how to get to this type of solution myself, so I was trying to simplify it. You are spot on tho. it does answer my question :)

Comment: You can also do the following, which gives an `ILookup<int, int>`: var classToStudent = studentToClass
    .SelectMany(
        pair => pair.Value.Select(val => new { Key = val, Value = pair.Key }))
    .ToLookup(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);